# How do I pass the "T" argument to as a method parameter using Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, instantiation

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3 with Java 6.  I’m having trouble trying to figure out what I need to substitute for “???” in the below code to get my method to work properly.  What I want is to instantiate an instance of my “T” class, invoking the generic constructor each time I instantiate the class.  Below is the method …

```
public class MyClass<T extends AbstractModel>
{

    public void myMethod()
    {
        …
        final HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        final T item = getInstance(???, data);

    }


    private T getInstance(final Class<T> class1,
                  final HashMap<String, String> data)
    {
        T retObj = null;
        try
        {
            Constructor ct = class1.getDeclaredConstructor(HashMap.class);
            Object[] argList = new Object[1];
            argList[0] = data;
            retObj = (T) ct.newInstance(argList);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }   // try
        return retObj;
    }   // getInstance
```

here is the constructor for my abstract model class …

```
public abstract class AbstractDIDOModel 
{

    protected HashMap<String, String> data;

    AbstractModel(final HashMap<String, String> data) 
    { 
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Comment: You just have to pass `class1` to `MyMethod`.

Comment: Yeah, but how?  THat is the gist of my question.  If you know, feel free to answer and I'll accept.

Comment: The called of `MyMethod` will have to know what to pass in for `class1`. You have to understand that there is no easy answer for this because Java doesn't actually store the type that `T` represents anywhere -- you have to keep track of that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trick if your class has the type parameters set, because in that case the type information is available at runtime. You can capture it and store it in a member field. Then you can use that field as the class inside your generic construction method.

```
public abstract class AbstractDIDOModel<T> 
{

 private Class<?> persistentClass = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType)  this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

 private T getInstance(final HashMap<String, String> data)
    {
        T retObj = null;
        try
        {
            Constructor ct = persistentClass.getDeclaredConstructor(HashMap.class);
            Object[] argList = new Object[1];
            argList[0] = data;
            retObj = (T) ct.newInstance(argList);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }   // try
        return retObj;
    }
```

Finally, declare your concrete classes as such:

```
public class MyClass<T extends AbstractModel>
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: How do I invoke the "getInstance" method of what you've defined from within "myMethod"?  Note that is not part of the AbstractModel class.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: It's cool -- instead of parameterizing the model, I was able to parameterize the class containing "myMethod", which ultimately needed to create the model.  So the trick solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass` should have the `Class<T>` passed in:

```
public class MyClass<T extends AbstractModel>
{
    private final Class<T> type;

    public MyClass(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; }

    public void myMethod()
    {
        …
        final HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        final T item = getInstance(type, data);

    }
```

Due to [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), no information of `T` exists at runtime and so you cannot obtain the type it refers to in most cases.

Note also that `Constructor` is typed, so you can replace this:

```
Constructor ct = class1.getDeclaredConstructor(HashMap.class);
//...
retObj = (T) ct.newInstance(argList);
```

With this:

```
Constructor<T> ct = class1.getDeclaredConstructor(HashMap.class);
//...
retObj = ct.newInstance(argList);
```

If your goal is to use `Class<T>` as a Factory, I would take a different approach however.  I would just accept a `Factory<T>`, where `Factory<T>` is an interface:

```
public interface Factory<T extends AbstractModel> {
   T create(HashMap<String, String> data);
}
```

Then creators of `MyClass<T>` can just implement this simply, without having to resort to reflection:

```
Factory<ConcreteModel> factory = new Factory<ConcreteModel>() {
   @Override
   public ConcreteModel create(HashMap<String, String> data) {
        return new ConcreteModel(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: The "MyClass" class is @Autowired using Spring (3.1.4.RELEASE) so I don't easily have a way to do this Factory thing you suggest.  Also there are dozens of these classes so there's be a lot of code changes.    I'll give this a go if I can't get a shorter implementation to work.